# Cross database SQL query performance in Azure

Tags: sql, azure, performance

I have a SQL query to join 2 tables in different databases (both are on-premises servers). The query is very slow. And I need to set them as Connected Database.

If 2 databases are both on Azure cloud, will the SQL query be quicker?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: For on-premises database, I am using SQL Server Management Studio. And use Power BI as reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the **external table** in the SQL server database and use it like a local table in the database. The external table will give you the super performance and reduce the latencies of connecting to other database to fetch the table data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=dedicated

Comment: Thanks. If I create External Tables to use a file saved in Blob Storage, will it automatically load the file's content into the database External table every day? I mean if I change the file content, will the External table's content got updated automatically?

Comment: External table feature is in Azure SQL server database. Loading the data into the table from blob storage would require az func or other means to push the data..

Comment: External table is a superior alternative to the database Synonyms